# How to refer to variable based on a number in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a program in Python 2.7 where I'm trying to refer to some variable based on a number a user inputs. I have the following:

```
p1 = "foo1"
p2 = "foo2"
p3 = "foo3"
p4 = "foo4"
p5 = "foo5"
p6 = "foo6"
p7 = "foo7"
k = raw_input('Enter number')
```

Clearly, having `if` statements on `k` would be redundant. Is there a more elegant way for my program to, given `k`, refer to the variable `pk`? For example, if `k=2`, the program would find variable `p2`.

Comment: I think you need [list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: If task is really that simple `print("foo"+k)` will work too.

Comment: Or you can use a dict https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych My bad, sorry.

Comment: if you use `input()` instead of `raw_input()`  , then the user may enter the variable name as input

Answer (score 2):

Keep the values in a list

```
l = ['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3']
```

Then you can access them by index

```
print l[0]
```

outputs

```
foo1
```

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Absolutely correct.  I'll fix my explanation

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a `dict`:

```
{1: 'foo1', 2: 'foo2', ...}[k]
```

However if you want to use a separate variable for each value then you can use `locals()` or `globals()`:

```
locals()['p%d' % k]
```

(supposing `type(k) == int` is `True`)

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [ "foo1", "foo2","foo3","foo4","foo5","foo6","foo7"] #save them as list

userinput = raw_input("Enter value:") #take input from user

print(lst[userinput]) #now the number from user will be the index
# to access your said object
```

Lets say i inputted 3 then result i get:

```
foo4
```